# How to add user to separate filesystem (Armel)

Tags: chroot, arm, adduser, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to work out how to add a user to a separate filesystem, as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core), specifically point 5: 
*Add a local user and password for the user, then add the user to the adm and sudo groups.*

I've read around chroot, but I don't believe this will work as the default command to run is `/bin/bash`, which would require the target fs to be binary compatible. In this case, the target filesystem is **Armel** so it's not compatible.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to AU. To get quality answers, make sure you emphasize what your question exactly is. In this case, I assume you relate to the ARM / ARMEL architecture.

Comment: Yes, as the target filesystem is ARMEL it's not possible to chroot into on an x86 system. I have got around this issue by mounting the filesystem on and ARMEL system and chrooting, but I wondered if there was a more direct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this page which explains exactly what I was trying to do to chroot into the target filesystem:

http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/OMAP_Ubuntu_Core#Chroot.27ing_into_the_Ubuntu_Core_Filesystem

It's then a simple case of running `adduser ubuntu` or similar.

Copied in case it goes dead:

## Chroot'ing into the Ubuntu Core Filesystem

One solution to customize your Ubuntu Core Filesystem is to do it from the Linux PC. Using a 'chroot' is sometimes quite convinient as you can run commands as you normally do on the ARM target. Here are some quick steps to get running:

### Chroot configuration on the Linux PC

Verify that on your Linux PC you have the 'qemu-user-static' Ubuntu package installed. This can be done with the following command line (on your Linux PC):

```
dpkg -l qemu-user-static
```

Have your SD Card mounted on your Linux PC and go to your rootfs Ubuntu Core folder, generally:

```
cd /media/rootfs
```

Copy the qemu for arm file:

```
cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static usr/bin/
```

If not done yet, have your network settings properly configured:

```
mv etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf.saved
cp /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf
```

Then, mount sys, proc and dev:

```
for m in `echo 'sys dev proc'`; do sudo mount /$m ./$m -o bind; done
```

Finally, chroot into your target filesystem:

```
sudo LC_ALL=C chroot . /bin/bash
```

You are now in your 'chroot' which means you can run commands like if you were on your target ARM device.

### Using the 'chroot'

The first step is to verify the network connection is fine. You can run:

```
apt-get update
```

You are now ready to install any new package in your Ubuntu Core Filesystem using APT tools.

### Getting out of the 'chroot'

Un-mount the target filesystem:
Make sure your at the / target FS and run the following commands:

```
for m in `echo 'sys dev proc'`; do sudo umount ./$m; done
```

Go back to your original network settings:

```
mv etc/resolv.conf.saved etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this will work (apart from your workaround: mounting the new filesystem it in an ARMEL system):

before doing `chroot`, do `mount --bind` the directories conntaining architecture-dependent binaries from your host system onto the corresponding pats in the new filesystem (`/bin/`, `/sbin/`, `/lib/` -- perhaps this will suffice for adding a user; or `/usr/*` as well, if not), then `chroot` and run the commands. `/etc/`, `/home/`, and `/var/` from the new filesystem will be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found a similar approach only the other day which worked perfectly, I'll post in another answer.